# Wrap Sqlite query callback function C++

Tags: c++, sqlite, callback

In sqlite3's C API, the function sqlite3_exec requires a callback function as a parameter, defined by

```
static int callback(void* data, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName)
```

I would like to have it work using a wrapper function to execute before the main callback. I.e. pass down my wrapper function to sqlite3_exec() which calls the actual callback.

A practical use case to illustrate what I am trying to achieve would be logging the response. As the code to log the response would (in my use case) not change across varying queries, since it can loop through the number of columns sent, I would like to have the logging defined *once* (i.e. in the wrapper) rather than re-defining it for all arbitrary amount of future callback functions defined.

This seems like the way to go but I don't know how to implement this.

I have tried creating a wrapper that takes in another argument - the actual callback, but passing this of course doesn't work as the function definition is then different.

**Update:**
Example code that does not compile

```
#include <sqlite3.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


class Callback
{
    public:
        Callback( int(*callback)(void* data, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName), void* data )
            : m_callback(callback), m_data(data) {}
        ~Callback(){}

    public:
        int CallbackWrapper(void* data, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName)
        {
            //Do something

            return m_callback(m_data, argc, argv, azColName);
        }

    private:
        int (*m_callback)(void* data, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName);
        void* m_data;
};


class Product_Queries
{
    public:
        Product_Queries() {}
        ~Product_Queries() {}

    public:
        int GetProductIds_Callback(void* data, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName){
            std::vector<int>* ids = (std::vector<int>*)data;
            ids->push_back(std::stoi(argv[0]));

            return 0;
        }
};



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    sqlite3* db;
    sqlite3_open("database.db", &db);

    Product_Queries product_queries;
    std::vector<int> productIds;
    Callback callback(product_queries.GetProductIds_Callback, (void*)&productIds); //Error here

    sqlite3_exec(db, "SELECT id FROM Products", callback.CallbackWrapper, nullptr, nullptr); //Error here


    sqlite3_close(db);

    return 0;
}
```

Both errors are `invalid use of non-static member function`

Comment: Have a structure storing the callback address and the `void*` pointer that would have been passed as the fourth parameter to `sqlite3_exec`. Call ``sqlite3_exec`` passing your wrapper callback and the address of that structure. The wrapper would then have all the information needed to call the original callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
struct OriginalCallback {
  int (*callback)(void*,int,char**,char**);
  void* data;
};

int WrapperCallback(void* data, int argc, char** argv, char** col_names) {
  // Do the work
  OriginalCallback* original = static_cast<OriginalCallback*>(data);
  return original->callback(original->data, argc, argv, col_names);
}

int WrapSqliteExec(sqlite3* db, const char *sql,
    int (*callback)(void*,int,char**,char**),
    void* data, char **errmsg) {
  OriginalCallback original{callback, data};
  return sqlite3_exec(db, sql, WrapperCallback, &original, errmsg);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in terms of creating a struct to store these, the function sqlite3_exec requires a static callback function. So the struct OriginalCallback would require it's 'callback' to be static, and then it won't be able to access the member 'data'. I suppose the whole class must be static then?

Comment: What is this "class" of which you speak? How does it fit into the picture? Show your original example, without the wrapper, and I'll show how to fit the wrapper into it.

Comment: Struct*. The struct in your code.

Comment: What about it? I'm not sure I quite follow.

Comment: The defined callback function in your struct needs to be static to compile due to sqlite's implementation of the exec function. This would mean then the void* data attribute must also be static for it to be accessible from the callback

Comment: "Static" as in static data member of some class? But in my example, there is no class; none of the functions are member functions, static or otherwise. In light of this, I don't understand what you are talking about. It would be best if you explain with a code example. The code I've shown should work as written. Have you tried it, and encountered some errors? Show a [mcve] of what you've tried and what errors you observed.

Comment: There was one typo in my code; fixed now. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qWq544WxG)

Comment: I have updated my question with a minimal reproducable example. I think the problem is grouping it in a class, whereas your code is global - but I don't want to have it global and potentially cause some linker errors or other sorts.

Comment: `Callback callback(product_queries.GetProductIds_Callback...` already won't compile, even before we get to anything related to SQLite. In order to call a non-static member function `GetProductIds_Callback`, a pointer or reference to `Product_Queries` instance is necessary. But you don't give `Callback` any such pointer or reference. How did you ever call `sqlite3_exec`? What did you pass to it before? Surely not `product_queries.GetProductIds_Callback`

Comment: As shown, `Product_Queries` doesn't store any state (no data members), so it's unclear why you are resistant to making `GetProductIds_Callback` static.

Comment: Good point, that's my bad. After some thought - doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: How this worked before - and the issue still persists - is that the `Callback` class which does store members needs to be static since to have it working I was passing in `Callback.CallbackWrapper` (but this was static, so made the members static too). I'm thinking now a workaround would be to have a static Callback function that casts `void* data` to a `Callback` type?

Comment: The standard approach is that you give `Callback` a static member and a non-static member. You call `sqlite3_exec` passing the static member for callback and `this` for `data`. When the static member is called back, it does something like `Callback* pThis = static_cast<Callback*>(data); pThis->NonStaticMember(argc, agv, colNames);`. The non-static member in turn has access to member variables.

Comment: This is what you have in your answer :). Thanks for the help! 
I must've been super fatigued not seeing that or coming up with what I came up with :D